# Avoid duplicated publication in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to export some data into a CSV file from a MySQL database using Meter/Sequelize. What I've done so far is to create a Meteor method called by the client which then call a server side function that return the data and I parse it into a csv string. My issue is returning the date client-side.

## What I did

I have my CSV String server-side and I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which can only be used client-side. 
My "solution" was to create a client-side collection in which I published the String.

### methods.js

```
run({exportParam}) {
if (!this.isSimulation) {
  query.booksQuery(exportParam.sorted, exportParam.filtered, 0).then( 
  result => {
    let CSVArr = [];
    result.rows.forEach((value) => {
      CSVArr.push(value.dataValues);
    });
    const CSVString = Baby.unparse(CSVArr,{ delimiter: ";"});<-CSV String
    console.log("CSVString : ", CSVString);
    Meteor.publish("CSVString", function() { <= publication
      this.added("CSVCollection", Random.id(), {CSVString: CSVString});
      this.ready();
    });
  });
 }
},
```

And on the client-side I subscribe to the publication this way :

### ExportButton.jsx

```
const handle = Meteor.subscribe('CSVString', {}, function() {
    const exportString = myTempCollection.findOne().CSVString;
    const blob = new Blob([exportString], {type:"text/plain;charset=utf 
    8"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test.csv");
  });
```

## My issue

It works great the first time I click my button and a CSV file is downloaded. The problem is that if I do it again I get the same file as the first one and I get this message on my console.

> Ignoring duplicate publish named 'CSVString'

I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the fact that every time I click the button the same "CSVString" publication is created.
I'd like to know to know if there is a solution to this problem or if my approach is wrong.

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that you are trying to publish to the same collection every time. I think you should only do the publish once, and do that separately from inserting a record into the collection.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. What you said makes sense but it seems to me that the `this.added` part can only be used inside the callback function of **Meteor.publish**. Do you think of another way of inserting a record in the collection?

Comment: Solved it thanks to @Mikkel 
I deleted methods.js created a publication which execute the code inside the run()